# Using custom image flags with language switcher module

Tags: overrides, module-display, multilingual, language

I want to display my custom flags images at the language switcher module. How can I replace the default flags of the module?

Comment: How did you manage to use .pngs instead of .gifs? i find no way of doing this. Nico.

Comment: @user2263: Your comment was for Brian Peat's comment below my answer. For my side, when I tried to use png's, I wasn't successful and gave up quickly. It might be possible though- but never ever tried again. I am okay with using gif's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the language siwtcher module gets the flags images from the directory

> /media/mod_languages/images

We can define which image should be used for each language, when creating/editing the **Content Languages** in **Language Manager**, through the **Image Prefix** selection.

According to the instructions that appear when hovering the field:

> Prefix of the image file for this language when using the "Use image
>   flags" Language Switcher basic option. Example: if 'en' is chosen,
>   then the image shall be en.gif. Images and CSS for this module are in
>   media/mod_languages/

**What does this say?**
That the Flags images should be in **.gif** format and uploaded in the mentioned directory.

There is no need to replace existing images as we can use any prefix we like for our flags.

The custom flags would be available in the **Edit Content Language layout**, and we can search for them by typing the prefix we gave them.

**Screenshot attached:**
[image]

Comment: To add to this, the images don't HAVE to be gifs. Here's a site I made that has custom flags that are PNG. On top of that I'm using retina.js and put the @2x images in there so on a retina machine their double the resolution.

http://shoresofgrace.com/en/

Comment: @brian-peat How did you change from gif to png?

Comment: Aha, looks like I did an html override and change .jpg to .png in the default.php file.

Comment: where is this default.php file located?

Comment: @Alexandros: I guess he meant the default.php of the languages switcher module.

Answer (score -1):

Used rereplacer extension from regular labs... (png in my images dir...

Comment: Hi Olo and welcome to JSE! Thank you for taking the time to add your own solution to this question. However this particular answer is rather poor in terms of being really helpful to other users. We tend to require more thorough answers here. So if you would consider to add more context to your answer, of how you managed to work out your solution (e.g. include steps, the workflow, or how the said extension helped you overall), that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Olo Please take our [tour] and then read [answer].